# What is this potted plant with dark green leaves and puffy white flowers on long stems?

Tags: identification, plant-care

I recently got this plant from my granddad, he can't take care of it anymore. Neither of us can figure out what it is, but he used to travel a lot so it wouldn't surprise me if he brought it from somewhere afar. I'd like to know how to take good care of it, so some help would be great!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a [*Haemanthus albiflos*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemanthus_albiflos) (common: elephant's ear / tongue, paintbrush plant).
It's native to South Africa.

You have a beautiful specimen here, good luck with it. It's rather easy to care for, given enough light and not too much water. For a start, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haemanthus_albiflos) or [here](https://www.rhs.org.uk/plants/details?plantid=896).